# Custom font css import not working on different browsers

Tags: css, font-face

My custom font doesn't work on different browsers. I imported 3 font weights using `@font-face`, all of them `.tiff`. But when I imported other variations `(.eot, .woff, .woff2, .svg)` all the text goes bold.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: lighter;
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: bolder;
}
*{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Bicyclette', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I also added Helvetica as a secondary font, but most browsers display it as Arial.

My website is deployed at novarion.ro.

My questions are: how can I make my custom font work on most browsers? And if that doesn't work, is there a way to keep it always Helvetica as the second option?

Comment: `Helvetica` is native to iOS and only commercially available elsewhere, other OS's don't carry that font face, unless users installed an alternative. The absent 'Helvetica' gets replaced with 'sans-serif', which is by default 'Arial' in most browsers.

Comment: Basically `font-family: 'Bicyclette', sans-serif;` will suffice as it will be replaced with the browsers default 'sans-serif' font face, either Helvetica, Arial or a user defined font for 'sans-serif'.

Answer (score 0):

Using numeric font-weight seems to be more robust.

You might also add a `font-style` value if there are any italic styles in your html/css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bicyclette';
    src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
 }

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Bicyclette';
   src: url('fonts/Bicyclette-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 700;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Bicyclette', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-weight:700;
}

.light{
    font-weight:300;
}
```

Besides, make sure all font-files are properly loaded (check your dev tool's console for 404s).

#### Helvetica Fallback

Provided, there is some Helvetica installed on a system - font-family names can be quite different.

You could add alternative font-family names as described by [Chris Coyier: Better Helvetica](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/better-helvetica/)
 to make the browser search for several font names.

```
body {
   font-family: Bicyclette, "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

However, this approach merely improves your chances of seeing a proper Helvetica, if one is available.